# JQPL custom query, having trouble returning list of objects in @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 Models, and `@ManyToMany` table. A User table, and a Picture table. The user table has a list of other users that specific one follows. The users have a `@OneToMany` association with each Picture.

User

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Picture> pics;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name="follows",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_id") 
)
private List<User> following;
```

Picture

```java
private String image_url;
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
```

The SQL Query to get all pictures associated with a all users (in User.following) is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `pictures` picture
WHERE `user_id` = '1' OR `user_id` IN (
    SELECT `following_id` FROM `follows` WHERE `user_id`= 1
)
```

But the follows table is not it's own Entity, I'm racking my brain on how to translate that SQL into HQL for the custom query. I'm still not able to figure it out and the closest I've gotten

```java
@Query(value="SELECT p FROM Picture p WHERE p.user = :user OR p.user IN(SELECT p.followers FROM p.followers WHERE user = :user)")
List<Picture> findByPictureFollower(@Param("user") User user);
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. I want to retrieve every picture object that's associated with each user object in the Following List Array on the User model. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it profile picture or user uploaded picture the relationship changes and manytoone is always eagre fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
@Query(value="SELECT p FROM Picture p WHERE p.user = :user OR p.user IN(SELECT f FROM User u JOIN p.followers f WHERE u = :user)")
List<Picture> findByPictureFollower(@Param("user") User user);
```